# Glowing particles not visible when rendering RGBA with Transparent Background

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have glowing particles (emmiter shader) visible in render with RGB background. Once I switch to render with Transparent background (Render -> Film -> Transparent) I cannot see the particles anymore. I can only see particles when there's another object in the scene behind them.

Comment: I had the same problem apparently when you set the the density in the smoke portion of the shader to 0 it won't render it on transparent bg.

Answer (score 1):

I have deleted the particle system and setup an new one, and this time it works. I cannot explain why I wasn't able to see the particles on the transparent background before.